Flutter Web app works local but not in firebase hosting
I'm working on a flutter web app, I run locally and works, then I deploy to firebase hosting but I get a white screen and nothing else.
I tried several options nothing works, looking on web and nothing found.
Any recommendations?

Can you describe more about the issues you encountered? for example photos, videos, etc.
